# LibGDX 3d implementing SSAO

Tags: java, libgdx, ssao

Is there a way to implement SSAO in a 3d scene in LibGDX?

My project extends ApplicationAdapter and uses a ModelBatch to render ModelInstances.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is: yes. Although my guess is that's not really the answer you are looking for. If so, make sure to carefully read the topics in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @Xoppa . Do you know of any articles of websites which explain the incorporation of ambient occlusion in LibGDX? I haven't been able to find anything.